# Error incompatible types: android.app.FragmentManager cannot be converted to android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager

Tags: java, android, tabs, navigation-drawer, swipeview

Error `Error incompatible types: android.app.FragmentManager cannot be converted to android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager` is drving me nuts.

In my app, I have 3 navigation drawer item, `timesheet`,`claim` and `view`, created in MainActivity. Now I wanted to add two `tabs` with `swipe view` in `view` item.

**MainActivity**  // for navigation drawer

```
   import android.app.Fragment;
   import android.app.FragmentManager;
   private void selectItem(int position) {

            Fragment fragment = null;

            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    fragment=new TimeSheet();
                    break;
                case 1:

                    fragment=new Claims1();
                    break;

                case 2:
                    fragment=new Viewview();
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
```

**TabsFragmentPagerAdapter.java**

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class TabsFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public TabsFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch(index) {
            case 0:
                return new UpdatePage2();
            case 1:
                return new Receipt();

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 2;
    }

}
```

**ViewView.java**

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.example.project.project.database.MyDatabaseHelper;

public class ViewView extends Fragment implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    InfoAPI sqlcon;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private MyDatabaseHelper dbHelper;
    private ListView listView;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsFragmentPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    private String[] tabs = {"Information", "receipt"};



    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View View1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewview1, container, false);
        listView = (ListView) View1.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        dbHelper = new MyDatabaseHelper(getActivity());
        sqlcon = new InfoAPI(getActivity());
        viewPager = (ViewPager) View1.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mAdapter = new TabsFragmentPagerAdapter(getActivity().getFragmentManager()); //here the error
        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tabs[i]).setTabListener(this));
        }
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int arg) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(arg);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        BuildList();
        return View1;
    }
```

Problem :

> Error:(49, 81) error: incompatible types: android.app.FragmentManager
>   cannot be converted to android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager

If changed `import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;` in `TabsFragmentPagerAdapter` to `import android.app.FragmentManager;`, the first issue solve but get this `Error:(12, 15) error: incompatible types: android.app.FragmentManager cannot be converted to android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager`...I have no idea how to fix ..

Edited

**MainActivity**

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
  case 2:
                    fragment=new ViewView();
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }

            if (fragment != null) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

                mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
                mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
                setTitle(mNavigationDrawerItemTitles[position]);
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

            } else {
                Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
            }
        }
```

**Error**

> Error:(148, 30) error: incompatible types: ViewView cannot be
>   converted to Fragment Error:(156, 69) error: incompatible types:
>   android.app.FragmentManager cannot be converted to
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager Error:(157, 80) error:
>   incompatible types: android.app.Fragment cannot be converted to
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Change

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
```

to

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
```

in every class. you are facing problems because in your **Fragment** creation class you are using support v4 fragment and in your **MainActivity** class you are inflating as a simple fragment.

You also need to change `getFragmentManager()` to `getSupportFragmentManager()`, and make sure they're extending a `FragmentActivity` class.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: After change, I get error on this line  `mAdapter = new TabsFragmentPagerAdapter(getActivity().getFragmentManager());`  Error   `Error:(49, 81) error: incompatible types: android.app.FragmentManager cannot be converted to android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager`

Comment: They'll also need to change `getFragmentManager()` to `getSupportFragmentManager()`, and make sure they're extending a `FragmentActivity` class.

Comment: change `android.app.FragmentManager` to `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager` in your MainActivity class

Comment: In mainActivity `public void onClick(View arg0) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        dialog.show(ft, "DatePicker");

    }`

Comment: Error `Error:(84, 34) error: cannot find symbol method getSupportFragmentManager()` , `Error:(85, 15) error: no suitable method found for show(android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction,String)
method DialogFragment.show(FragmentManager,String) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction cannot be converted to FragmentManager)
method DialogFragment.show(android.app.FragmentTransaction,String) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction cannot be converted to android.app.FragmentTransaction)`

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/ & https://androidbelieve.com/navigation-drawer-with-swipe-tabs-using-design-support-library/ please above link

Comment: The above mentioned changes have to be done in every fragments which you declare. This correction helped me